# More decimal places for standard Quantity field possible?

Tags: apex, standard-objects, standard-field

All across Salesforce, there are lots of standard Quantity fields on standard objects, such as

- OpportunityLineItem.Quantity | Number(10,2)
- QuoteLineItem.Quantity | Number(10,2)
- OrderItem.Quantity | Number(16,2)

Now all these fields are defined as Number(16,2) or Number(10,2). What if we need more decimal places like Decimal(10,6)? Is this possible, or do we need to switch to a custom field - and as domino-consequence, do we need to swithc the entire mechanisms of TotalPrice-calculation on custom fields plus calculation-logic, too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request [more decimals on prices](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Product-Price-What-is-the-More-decimals-on-price-feature-1327109134062&language=en_US&type=1), but not more decimals on [quantities](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bp7mAAC). If that might work for you, you can request this feature by submitting a case. Otherwise, be sure to vote for that Idea. You might need to readjust your concept of what a quantity is and request additional decimals for prices. I realize this isn't ideal, but it beats trying to build a system from scratch. Building something custom will affect forecasting, default reports, default field behaviors (e.g. Amount auto-calculation), etc, many of which can't be changed to use your custom field(s). Also, you can't remove the default Quantity field except to default everything to 1, which will probably also have adverse effects.

Comment: as always: brilliant answer!